# Interfacing Python with Oracle Middleware Forms client side application

Tags: python, oracle

My company uses Oracle's Middleware Forms application to interface with our pl.SQL database. The database engineers and our data analysts have access to the actual database and everyone else has access to it through OFM Forms. I'm looking for a way to interact with OFM Forms using Python.

I would like to do with without GUI automation because I've been playing with GUI automation for the last week and it isn't working well. OFM just sort of makes the various modules I have tried wonky and unresponsive. For the record I have tried SendKeys, PyAutoGUI, Automa, SendKeys.Ctypes, and another but I can't recall what it is called. The only success I have had with automation is using AutoHotKey.

Does anyone know if there is a COM interface or a non-GUI interface to interact with OFM Forms? If not, anyone have any other suggestions for a GUI automation?

Comment: What sort of tasks do you want to use Python for?

Comment: @APC a few things. Mainly database updating. I will be given an excel spreadsheet that has all the updates to the database I need to make and I then have to enter each update. Manually this involves pulling up the proper school, then finding the right subject and course number.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue.
Best option I found so far is a pywinauto.

```
from pywinauto import Application, keyboard
ofm = pywinauto.Application().start('C:\orant\BIN.....
```

I havenot found how to send keys directly but while the app is active I'm just typing:

```
keyboard.SendKeys('not_my_real_login')
keyboard.SendKeys('{TAB 1}')
```

Comment: This was how I solved it at the time. I've since been hired by our IT team and now have the appropriate permissions and clout to access our pl/sql database directly, which has drastically increased productivity.